# Why is my BeginInvoke method not async?

Tags: c#, multithreading, begininvoke

In order to avoid freezing of GUI, I wanted to run method connecting to DB asynchronously. Therefore I have written this:

```
DelegatLoginu dl = ConnectDB;

IAsyncResult ar = dl.BeginInvoke(null, null);

var result = (bool)dl.EndInvoke(ar);
```

But it is still freezing and I do not understand why. I thought `BeginInvoke` ensures the invoked code runs in another thread. Thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Calling EndInvoke() will block until the BeginInvoke() call has completed.

You need this kind of pattern in order for your long-running method to invoke a callback when it finishes:

```
public void DemoCallback()
{
    MethodDelegate dlgt = new MethodDelegate (this.LongRunningMethod) ;
    string s ;
    int iExecThread;

    // Create the callback delegate.
    AsyncCallback cb = new AsyncCallback(MyAsyncCallback);

    // Initiate the Asynchronous call passing in the callback delegate
    // and the delegate object used to initiate the call.
    IAsyncResult ar = dlgt.BeginInvoke(3000, out iExecThread, cb, dlgt); 
}

public void MyAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    string s ;
    int iExecThread ;

    // Because you passed your original delegate in the asyncState parameter
    // of the Begin call, you can get it back here to complete the call.
    MethodDelegate dlgt = (MethodDelegate) ar.AsyncState;

    // Complete the call.
    s = dlgt.EndInvoke (out iExecThread, ar) ;

    MessageBox.Show (string.Format ("The delegate call returned the string:   \"{0}\", 
                                and the number {1}", s, iExecThread.ToString() ) );
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use AsyncCallBack class or I can pass simple delegate?

Comment: It has to be an AsyncCallBack delegate, i.e. your function must look like the MyAsyncCallback() example above - return void, and take in IAsyncResult as a parameter.

Comment: I have tested this code locally and it doesn't work (it compiles, but it does not show anything on screen): http://ideone.com/V8b2NY

Answer (score 5):

See the description of `EndInvoke` [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315582), specifically:

> The EndInvoke() function is used to
>   retrieve the results of the
>   asynchronous call. It can be called
>   anytime after BeginInvoke(). If the
>   asynchronous call has not completed
>   yet, EndInvoke() blocks until it
>   completes.

Answer (score 2):

You're immediately blocking your UI thread when calling `dl.EndInvoke(ar)`. This kind of defeats the whole purpose of having an async call.

Comment: Well, it was mz guess..so what is this good for? I thought it does all the connection stuff in backround and then only returns :(

Comment: The `BeginXxx` returns just after the call, at which point the connection stuff is being handled in the background. When the result is ready, you'll get notified (either by a callback or by polling on the `WaitHandle` in the `IAsyncResult` returned by the `BeginXxx` call). At this point you invoke the `EndXxx` to retrieve the result (or get exceptions which happended in the call). Calling `EndXxx` early forces a wait until the result is ready.

Answer (score 1):

There's 4 different patterns to using the async model in .NET [as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784928/c-four-patterns-in-asynchronous-execution/1785017#1785017) covers very well.

**You're using the *"I'll call you"* approach**. However if you want to wait until the work item has finished, the best technique is to use a `Mutex` (the `WaitHandle`):

```
void Run()
{
    Action<string> doWork = DoWork;
    IAsyncResult result = doWork.BeginInvoke("I will call you", null, null);

    // You "call the method" - wait 10 seconds for the method to finish.
    bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10 * 1000);
}

void DoWork()
{
}
```

I suspect you don't want to block, in which case *"fire and forget"* causes the least headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a method to be called when the call is completed in BeginInvoke (like dl.BeginInvoke(null, OnConnectCompleted)). Then the thread will not be blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Call to EndInvoke will block your current thread. You should pass a delegate into the BeginInvoke instead of calling the EndInvoke