# How to wait until a method is started & finished?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have *method A* that runs on *thread #1*.

I also have *method B* that runs on *thread #2*.

Method A writes to a shared object a function C (method that receives an object value and returns a Boolean value) that should be executed on some event via method B. (method B is a TCP listener method that runs forever)

I wish that method A will wait until that event occurs AND the C is finished. Currently its implemented with a Sleep based for loop (with timeout and such).

Let me make myself more clear, the flow is like this:

Method B (on thread #2): `while(true) { process data, if data has x then someFunc(..) }`

Method A (on thread #1): `someFunc = (obj) => {...};` `wait until someFunc is executed by B & is finished;` `do more stuff`

Whats the smartest way of achieving this?

Comment: Look at [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's made for this sort of thing, there are examples at MSDN as well.

Comment: How about a [`Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: You can get the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784928/c-sharp-four-patterns-in-asynchronous-execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent`

```
private AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
void MethodB()
{
   //process data
   if(condition)
   {
       signal.Set();//Say you're finished
   }
}

void MethodA()
{
    //Do something

    signal.WaitOne();//Wait for the signal
    //Here do whatever you want. We received signal from MethodB
}
```

I recommend reading http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Answer (score 1):

Use a lock and the Monitor class.

```
private object _lock = new object();
...
private void StartTaskAndWait()
{
   lock (_lock)
   {
      new Task(DoSomething).Start();
      Monitor.Wait()
   }
}
```

Use Pulse at the end of the task method to "wake up" the waiting thread.

```
lock (_lock)
{
   Monitor.Pulse(_lock);
}
```