# How can I confirm how many tests are running in parallel?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm running my unit tests on a 16-core machine. I can't see any difference in elapsed time when using no parallelization parameter, `--workers=1` and `--workers=32`. I'd like to confirm that NUnit really is running the expected number of simultaneous tests, so that I don't spend time hunting down a non-existent problem in my test code.

I have `[Parallelizable]` (default scope, `ParallelScope.Self`) on the common base class. It is defined not on any other class or method. I'm using `nunit3-console`, both via Jenkins and on my local command line.

Is there a way to tell that tests are running in parallel? NUnit is reporting the correct number of worker threads, but there's no report saying (for example) how many tests were run in each thread.

```
Run Settings
    ProcessModel: Multiple
    RuntimeFramework: net-4.5
    WorkDirectory: C:\Jenkins\workspace\myproject
    NumberOfTestWorkers: 16
```

I can log the start and finish times of each test then manually check that there's a reasonable number of overlaps; is there any simpler and more repeatable way of getting what I want?

Comment: [Which pattern is nunit using](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784928/c-sharp-four-patterns-in-asynchronous-execution). [pnunit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5) could be another option. Does cmd line tasklist contain the child processes of nunit?

Comment: Isn't nunit3 essentially nunit2+pnunit (+ some excellent refactoring)?

Comment: The tests are totally independent (well, as much as web requests are). So "fire and forget" from the list in that question you linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned on `--trace=Verbose` which produces a few files. `InternalTrace.<pid1>.log` and `InternalTrace.<pid2>.<dll_name>.log` together contained a thorough description of what was happening during the tests. The per-agent log (the one with the DLL name in the log file name) was pretty clear about the state of parallelization.

```
16:13:40.701 Debug [10] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing test1
16:13:47.506 Debug [10] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing test2
16:13:52.847 Debug [10] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing test3
16:13:58.922 Debug [10] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing test4
16:14:04.492 Debug [10] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing test5("param1")
16:14:09.720 Debug [10] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing test5("param2")
16:14:14.618 Debug [10] WorkItemDispatcher: Directly executing test5("param3")
```

That third field looks like a thread ID to me. So I believe that the agent is running only one test at a time, even though (I think..) I've made all the tests parallelizable and they're all in different test fixtures.

Now I've just got to figure out what I've done wrong and why they're not running in parallel...

Comment: Hi Paul - looking at a similar problem now. Did you ever reach a conclusion on what may be wrong?

Comment: Yes.  `[Parallelizable]` is not inheritable: see [Charlie Poole's comment](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nunit-discuss/aXduucHkMF0) on the NUnit-Discuss group. I took his advice and gave the assembly the attribute via AssemblyInfo.cs, then annotated the non-parallel tests with `[Apartment(ApartmentState.STA)]`. I can look for a question (or create one) to add this as an answer to, if that's useful.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I did a bit more digging this afternoon however, and I think mine was memory limited...after closing visual studio it started taking up to 4GB memory before it hit the next limit, and run times improved. Thanks for the debug details above however, that pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I could be mistaken but it seems to me that to set [`Parallelizable]` parameter is not enough to make tests run in parallel. You also need to create nodes that will run tests. So if you use Jenkins you have to create Jenkins Slaves and only then your tests will be run in parallel.

**So what I want to tell is that as I understand there is no possibility to run tests in parallel on one PC.**

If there is such a possibility (to run tests in parallel on the same machine) it would be really great and I struggle to hear about it!

Comment: No, it works fine if I add the Parallelizable attribute to each TestFixture. If we went so far as to use separate Jenkins jobs, then parallelization would not come into it. I could run non-parallel tests in parallel using that technique.