# Testing Code With Threads in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading, unit-testing

I need to test my vigorously tested code works when called by many threads

So I am calling the code in a loop in a TestMethod using TreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

however there does not seem to be anyway of holding the current thread while all the threads kicked off are still running.

i.e. *pretend code....*

using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

```
10 create a server

20 for( a number of iterations ) start a thread running a function

30 while all the threads are still doing stuff hang on to the server

40 now dispose of the server
```

Without the wait my unit test is disposing of the server before the job is done.

Any insights gratefully received...?

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of reference counting for the "server" object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your goal for the **main thread to wait for all the other threads to finish before disposing the server**?

If so, you should take a look at a very detailed answer I got to a similar question that I asked some time ago. Many different approaches that you should consider are included in the answer.

**[The answer that was given is located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net/2228508#2228508).**

Hope that helps!

Comment: yes, just to say thread.Join doesn't work in the test framework - no idea why. Anyhow, I'll have a good read on the link you sent tomorrow (very late here eyes closing and wife snoring) - thanks for the swift reply

Comment: From this answer I will be using Join - thanks for the pointer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about .NET, but in java I would do this

```
10 create a server

20 for( a number of iterations ) start a thread running a function

30 while(all the threads are still doing stuff){
    MainThread.Sleep(xMiliseconds)
}

40 now dispose of the server
```

That way the MainThread will continually loop, sleep, loop, sleep, until all the threads are done, then it will dispose of the server.

Answer (score 0):

Join() is the easiest.  If you can't do that, you can create an event for each thread and wait for the event to be signled.  Alternatively, you could create a semaphore with an initial count for each thread and wait for all threads to release the semaphore.

Comment: join doesn't work in a test, unless your debugging then its fine

Comment: Join does work after all, something is throwing an error during the test which doesn't when in debug..