# Create multiple threads and wait for all of them to complete

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

How can I create multiple threads and wait for all of them to complete?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

It depends which version of the .NET Framework you are using. .NET 4.0 made thread management a whole lot easier using Tasks:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());
        Task task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());
        Task task3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doStuff());

        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3);
                Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
    }

    static void doStuff()
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
```

In previous versions of .NET you could use the `BackgroundWorker` object, use `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`, or create your threads manually and use `Thread.Join()` to wait for them to complete:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread t1 = new Thread(doStuff);
    t1.Start();

    Thread t2 = new Thread(doStuff);
    t2.Start();

    Thread t3 = new Thread(doStuff);
    t3.Start();

    t1.Join();
    t2.Join();
    t3.Join();

    Console.WriteLine("All threads complete");
}
```

Comment: The Task API is by far the cleanest solution.

Comment: There are some limitations to be aware of - if you require a thread to have a particular priority, then you can't use Tasks. Well, technically you could, but it is a bad idea to change thread priority of a thread inside Task because the thread belongs to a threadpool and so your custom priority could affect some other code.

Answer (score 41):

I think you need [WaitHandler.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitall?view=netcore-3.1#overloads). Here is an example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numOfThreads = 10;
    WaitHandle[] waitHandles = new WaitHandle[numOfThreads];

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++)
    {
        var j = i;
        // Or you can use AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent
        var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset);
        var thread = new Thread(() =>
                                {
                                    Thread.Sleep(j * 1000);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Thread{0} exits", j);
                                    handle.Set();
                                });
        waitHandles[j] = handle;
        thread.Start();
    }
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitHandles);
    Console.WriteLine("Main thread exits");
    Console.Read();
}
```

FCL has a few more convenient functions.

(1) [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___), as well as its overloads, when you want to do some tasks in parallel (and with no return values).

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething1()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething2()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething3())
};
Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

(2) [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=netcore-3.1#overloads) when you want to do some tasks with return values. It performs the operations and puts the results in an array. It's thread-safe, and you don't need to using a thread-safe container and implement the add operation yourself.

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething1()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething2()),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetSomething3())
};
var things = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: @Kirk: I was going to add an example just now but had to go to a meeting.

Comment: good explaination for 'no return' and 'return' values from method!

Comment: Your thread code was exactly what I was looking for since I wanted to simulate lots of requests, not just use the few threads the "smarter" TPL methods give me.

Answer (score 9):

I've made a very simple extension method to wait for all threads of a collection:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;

namespace Extensions {
    public static class ThreadExtension {
        public static void WaitAll (this IEnumerable<Thread> threads) {
            if (threads != null) {
                foreach (Thread thread in threads) {
                    thread.Join();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you simply call:

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
// Add your threads to this collection
threads.WaitAll();
```

Comment: I would rather use `ThreadHelpers.WaitAll(threadCollection)` .. in any case, this is largely what I use for tests. I've rarely had the need to 'wait all' in actual code.

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the principle of operation?

Answer (score 5):

In .NET 4.0, you can use the [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl).

In earlier versions, you can create a list of `Thread` objects in a loop, calling `Start` on each one, and then make another loop and call `Join` on each one.

Comment: @user: If you call `Join` right after starting the thread, you'll end up waiting for it to finish before starting any other threads.  You need to start _all_ of the threads, **then** `Join` all of them.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use the [`Task class`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task) (for instance, in .NET 3.5), you can just start all your threads, and then add them to the list and [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.join) them in a `foreach` loop.

Example:

```cs
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

// Start threads
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int tmp = i; // Copy value for closure
    Thread t = new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine(tmp));
    t.Start();
    threads.Add(t);
}

// Join threads (wait threads)
foreach (Thread thread in threads) {
    thread.Join();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a better way, but the following describes how I did it with a counter and **background worker** thread.

```
private object _lock = new object();
private int _runningThreads = 0;

private int Counter{
    get{
        lock(_lock)
            return _runningThreads;
    }
    set{
        lock(_lock)
            _runningThreads = value;
    }
}
```

Now whenever you create a worker thread, increment the counter:

```
var t = new BackgroundWorker();
// Add RunWorkerCompleted handler

// Start thread
Counter++;
```

In work completed, decrement the counter:

```
private void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Counter--;
}
```

Now you can check for the counter anytime to see if any thread is running:

```
if(Couonter>0){
    // Some thread is yet to finish.
}
```

Comment: You don't need a lock. In fact, since you only write the property form the UI thread, you don't need anything.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think the lock is correct; he is decrementing the counter in an event handler that is fired when each worker completes.

Comment: @Mark: The Completed event is always fired on the UI thread.  Also, the lock won't have any effect; Int32 read and writes are atomic.  Had there been thread issues, the lock wouldn't help; he'd need to call `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: The lock won't work for Counter-- as the counter is unprotected between the get/set.

Comment: @Greg: Exactly.  Multi-threading is hard.  Slapping a lock in each member isn't nearly enough.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I understand what @SLaks is saying and will use `Interlocked.Increment`, but @Greg how is counter unprotected?

Comment: @The: What if two threads run `Counter--` at once? This operation involves separate reads and writes; one of the decrements will be lost.  The `Interlocked` class avoids this.

Comment: However, since you're using BackgroundWorker, you don't need to worry about any of this; the Completed event always fires on the UI thread.

Comment: thanks @SLaks I'll visit http://www.albahari.com/ to get a refresher on threading soon :D

Comment: how does it compared with Join()?

Comment: @User: This technique cannot be used to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Most proposed answers don't take into account a time-out interval, which is very important to prevent a possible deadlock. Next is my sample code. (Note that I'm primarily a Win32 developer, and that's how I'd do it there.)

```
//'arrRunningThreads' = List<Thread>

//Wait for all threads
const int knmsMaxWait = 3 * 1000;           //3 sec timeout
int nmsBeginTicks = Environment.TickCount;
foreach(Thread thrd in arrRunningThreads)
{
    //See time left
    int nmsElapsed = Environment.TickCount - nmsBeginTicks;
    int nmsRemain = knmsMaxWait - nmsElapsed;
    if(nmsRemain < 0)
        nmsRemain = 0;

    //Then wait for thread to exit
    if(!thrd.Join(nmsRemain))
    {
        //It didn't exit in time, terminate it
        thrd.Abort();

        //Issue a debugger warning
        Debug.Assert(false, "Terminated thread");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I could not instantiate my objects on the the thread pool with `Task.Run()` or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`. They would not synchronize my long running delegates correctly.

I needed the delegates to run asynchronously, pausing my main thread for their collective completion. The `Thread.Join()` would not work since I wanted to wait for collective completion in the middle of the parent thread, not at the end.

With the `Task.Run()` or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, either all the child threads blocked each other or the parent thread would not be blocked, ... I couldn't figure out how to go with `async` delegates because of the re-serialization of the `await` syntax.

Here is my solution using Threads instead of Tasks:

```
using (EventWaitHandle wh = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset))
{
  int outdex = mediaServerMinConnections - 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < mediaServerMinConnections; i++)
  {
    new Thread(() =>
    {
      sshPool.Enqueue(new SshHandler());
      if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref outdex) < 1)
        wh.Set();
    }).Start();
  }
  wh.WaitOne();
}
```