# C# Making Basic Multithreaded Loop Return the Correct Values

Tags: c#, multithreading

First off, I'm new to C#, and this is the first program I've written that uses threads. Sorry if it's a bit basic.

Here's my app:

```
    class Program
{
    static void AddNumbers()
    {
        int count = 0; 

        for (int counter = 0; counter < 90000000; counter++)
        {
            count += counter;
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            // Non-threaded
            //AddNumbers();
            //Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString());

            // Threaded
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                //Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                AddNumbers();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString());
            }).Start();
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}", stopwatch.Elapsed);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It simply loops `i` times and adds a bunch of numbers each time. When I run the `AddNumbers()` version non-multithreaded, it correctly displays `1, 2, 3...` etc, but when I run it multithreaded, it returns the same indexes 2-3 times, skips some, and returns the stopwatch value before all the threads have executed.

Can someone please help spot where my error is and most of all clarify my thinking about how threads work in C#? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I run the AddNumbers() version non-multithreaded, it correctly displays 1, 2, 3... etc, but when I run it multithreaded, it returns the same indexes 2-3 times, skips some

It happens, because `i` is captured, but changed in outside loop.

Read more about it here:

[Captured variable in a loop in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271440/captured-variable-in-a-loop-in-c-sharp)
http://www.trycatchthat.com/csharp/fundamentals/2016/02/29/csharp-closure-loops.html

In order to make it work properly you need to save a local copy:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    // Non-threaded
    //AddNumbers();
    //Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString());

    // Threaded
    int iCopy = i;
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

        AddNumbers();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine((iCopy + 1).ToString());
    }).Start();
}
```

> returns the stopwatch value before all the threads have executed

It happens, because you actually never join your threads and wait for them to execute.
It can be achieved by storing all threads and calling `thread.Join()`:

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[50];

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    // Non-threaded
    //AddNumbers();
    //Console.WriteLine((i + 1).ToString());

    // Threaded
    int iCopy = i;
    threads[i] = new Thread(() =>
    {
        //Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

        AddNumbers();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine((iCopy + 1).ToString());
    });
    thread[i].Start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    threads[i].Join();
```

Read more about waiting for threads to complete here:

[Create multiple threads and wait all of them to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4190949/create-multiple-threads-and-wait-all-of-them-to-complete)

This is how people used to do it before TPL has been invented.
Now, general rule is not to use `Thread`, but use `Task` or `Parallel` instead.

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();

Task[] tasks = new Task[50];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    int iCopy = i;
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(() => {
        AddNumbers();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine((iCopy + 1).ToString());
    });
} 

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Thanks Yeldar. I changed `Task.StartNew` to `Task.Run` and it worked fine. I appreciate the explanation and help.

Comment: @KyleCarlson I am glad it helped. Oh, yes, indeed. It is either `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` which are pretty synonymous, and I have mixed this up :D