# How can I force the system to wait creating a new thread if the previous is thread still running?

Tags: c#, multithreading, join, timer

I am using `System.Timers` in my program.

As we know each interval new thread is created to handle the `OnTimedEvent`.

I am looking for way to force the system to wait creating a new thread if the previous thread is still running.

My `OnTimedEvent` execute some method and I would like to wait until the method is finished

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: thread.Join() // Waits here until thread is finished.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net

Comment: Do you have to use a timer?  Can you not just loop the thread and, at the end, calculate how many ms to go until the next run and, if positive, sleep for that time?

Comment: @Martin James- I use this application as windows service so I would like use timer and noe while(true) loop,@MrFox as I said I use timer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mistaken in the sense that no new thread will be created when the `Elapsed` event is fired. The event will be raised on the the .NET threadpool, so an arbitrary thread will process it.

One way to do what you want is to `Stop` the timer at the start of your event handler and to `Start` it again once it is finished. Like this:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += HandleTimerElapsed;
timer.Start();

...

private void HandleTimerElapsed(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    var t = (System.Timers.Timer)s;
    t.Stop();

    try {
        ... do some processing
    }
    finally { // make sure to enable timer again
        t.Start();
    } 
}
```

The other option is to set the `AutoReset` property of the timer to false. This way the timer will only be raised once. Then you can call `Start` when you want it to start again. So the above code would change to include a `timer.AutoReset = false;` at the beginning and then you don't need to call `Stop` inside the handler. This is a bit safer as the above method probably has a race condition in the sense that if the system is under load your handler might not be guaranteed to execute before the timer elapses again.