# How to get thread execution complete event

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am creating a new thread to call a function in it.

```
Thread th = new Thread(My_Function);
th.start();
```

I wanna do something on completion of this thread execution.

Is there any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At least two possible solutions:

**BackgroundWorker**

Use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to execute your code, and use the [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event to execute the code that is run after completion.

A `BackgroundWorker` wraps the event based asynchronous pattern into a very easy to use mechanism, complete with progress reporting and cancellation. See this [BackgroundWorker tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481304/how-to-use-a-backgroundworker) SO answer .

**Tasks (.NET 4.0 and above)**

Use a [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) object, and use the [`ContinueWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith.aspx) method to define the code that needs to be executed after completion of the first task.

Comment: The Task link is very good. I ended up with something like 
Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("Step 0")).Wait();
Task.Run(() => MessageBox.Show("Step 2")).Wait(); which worked perfectly.

Answer (score -2):

You can use something such

```
if(th.isAlive())
{...}
```