# when does a method return if a new thread is started inside it

Tags: c#

Suppose I have some code that looks like this:

```
public SomeMethod() {

   foreach (x...)
   {
     if (SomeCondition)
     {
        var SomeVariable = x;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeOtherMethod(SomeVariable));
     }
   }

   return SomeValue;
}
```

If `SomeOtherMethod` is called and started in a new thread, does a) `SomeMethod` wait until that thread is finished running before returning or b) the method return and then the threads of `SomeOtherMethod` just continue on their own even after `SomeMethod` returned?

Reason I ask is that I need to wait until all `SomeOtherMethods` finish before exit SomeMethod.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that a quiz you're facing?

Comment: Hint: what are threads for?

Comment: It's a situation in my code. The threads are database calls.

Comment: All you're really asking for is how to wait until another thread completes. That has been [answered quite comprehensively already](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2228508/716118).

Comment: Then I guess the question should be "how to wait for another thread to finish?"

Comment: I dummied down the answer to just 2 options so can I get an a) or b) instead of links?? Thanks.

Comment: @frenchie the answer is, I believe, B)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collect all the tasks in a collection, then call [`Task.WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235659.aspx) on it:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (x...)
{
    if (SomeCondition)
    {
        var someVariable = x;
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SomeOtherMethod(someVariable));
     }
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

Note that in .NET 4.5 when writing an async method, you would use:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

as `Task.WhenAll` itself doesn't block, but returns a task which completes when all the others have. (Note the difference between **When**All and **Wait**All here - very different methods!)

(Additionally, with .NET 4.5 you can use [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run.aspx) instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew`, just for convenience.)

Comment: lol...you just had to one up me with your fancy 4.5 knowledge!!

Comment: I just love Jon's answers! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) can be used to track and wait for all Tasks to complete.  StartNew returns a Task.  Track all returned values in an array and pass it to WaitAll.

E.G.

```
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        while (condition)
        {
            if (true)
            {                    
                Task temp = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 0);
                tasks.Add(temp);
            }
            //...
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```