# Wait until my thread is finished

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public delegate void FileEventHandler(string file);
public event FileEventHandler fileEvent;

public void getAllFiles(string path)
{
    foreach (string item in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
    {
        try
        {
            getAllFiles(item);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }
    }

    foreach (string str in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.pcap"))
    {
        // process my file and if this file format OK raised event to UI and add the file to my listbox
        FileChecker fileChecker = new FileChecker();
        string result = fileChecker.checkFIle(str);
        if (result != null)
            fileEvent(result);
    }
}

private void btnAddDirInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ThreadStart ts = delegate { getAllFiles(pathToSearch); };
        Thread thread = new Thread(ts);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
}
```

I want to wait until thread has finish its job and then update my UI

Comment: Where's your thread?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net?rq=1 Check this out

Comment: I am calling getAllFiles() via another thread from the mail UI

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you need unless we see more information.  You definitely need to lock something or add a mutex, we just can't tell what.

Comment: Can't you use a BackGroundWorker? They were made for this purpose.

Comment: within fileChecker.checkFIle is the thread?

Comment: why not use a worker add an event handler "OnWorkDone", call it when thread is finished and update the ui? Here is a good thread example to create a splash screen: [link](http://mrbool.com/how-to-make-a-splash-screen-in-csharp/26598)

Comment: See my update, added the thread

Comment: Why not Thread.Join()?

Comment: @Naren Because then you block the UI thread.

Comment: use Async and Await http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: You shouldn't be swallowing exceptions as you are in `getAllFiles`.  If you have a try/catch then you should be handling the exceptions (at the very, very least, you should be logging them somewhere so that you know they're happening) and if you can't handle them then it's better to just let them bubble up.

Comment: @Servy But the OP said "I want to wait until thread has finish its job and then update my UI".I can't understand it.

Comment: @Naren You need to ensure that the UI is updated when the background work is finished *without* blocking the main thread.  If you've ever done any desktop style programming at all, it would be a problem you are very frequently faced with, and there are *lots* of resources on the subject all over the internet.

Comment: @Servy Thanks ,I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Task Parallel Library, rather than explicit tasks, along with the asynchrony language features to do this very easily:

```
private async void btnAddDirInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => getAllFiles(pathToSearch));
    lable1.Text = "all done!";
}
```

Comment: If this runs in a separate thread, the Text attribute assignment will throw a runtime exception.

Comment: @JonathanHenson Look at the method.  This is the button click event handler.  It runs in the UI thread.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that. Await will not block the UI thread either?

Comment: @JonathanHenson No, it will not.  It will schedule the remainder of the method as a continuation of the awaited task and then return control back to the caller.

Comment: +1 for realising the requirement is not necessarily to wait, but to simply update the UI once the task has completed, and providing a succint solution.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use Tasks?

```
await Task.Run(() => getAllFiles(pathToSearch));
```

Your method will be run on a separate thread, freeing your main thread to keep the UI responsive.
As soon as the task completes, the control will return to your UI thread.

Edit: Don't forget to mark your button_click method as `async void`

Comment: just curious, is it possible to update a progress bar this way?

Comment: @Koryu You would use the `Progress` class to update a progress bar.

Comment: Do you mean running a task that periodically updates a progress bar? You can, but I don't think tasks were designed for this purpose.

Comment: @dcastro The TPL does indeed have a mechanism for handling it.  It is the `Progress` class, as I said before.  That's the intended mechanism for solving that problem with this style of programming.

Comment: Thanks @Servy, I wasn't aware of the `Progress` class. If anyone else is interested in this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis.aspx will help.

Comment: ty, sounds interesting, i usually use backround worker with progress bar. didnt know it would work with a task. i just found this [example on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/129447/Progress-Reporting-in-C-5-Async)