# How do i ensure statement gets executed after all the threads have completed execution

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

say my main thread calls a loop which makes new threads and starts them on some other function.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
        Thread thread = new Thread(start);
        thread.Start();
}
call_This_Function_After_All_Threads_Have_Completed_Execution();
```

How can i ensure that my method gets called only after all the other threads have completed execution.

Comment: [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) will make your life lot easier. :)

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net

Answer (score 1):

You can use AutoResetEvent-s. Declare an AutoResetEvent array where all the threads can reach it.

```
AutoResetEvent[] events = new AutoResetEvent[numberOfThreads];
```

Start threads like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++)
{
    events[i] = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    Thread thread = new Thread(start);
    thread.Start(i);
}
WaitHandle.WaitAll(events);
call_This_Function_After_All_Threads_Have_Completed_Execution();
```

And finally don't forget to call the Set() method in the threads:

```
 void start(object i)
 {
       //... do work
       events[(int) i].Set();
 }
```