# Waiting for a ThreadState to be "Stopped" in a Button Click Event

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, button

I'm having some issues while waiting for a `ThreadState` during the `Click` event of a button control.
Whenever I click my button it'll execute the code below.
The problem with this is that it won't wait until the `ThreadState` is "Stopped", so it never enables `btnImportData` or `btnExportBellijst`.

I've tried `t.Join()` but that freezes my whole form and I use a `RichTextBox` as logger, so that'd result in a logger that freezes for a few seconds and then shows a lot of text at once.
The reason I put the `ImportData` function on another Thread is to keep the form running so people can see the logs happening realtime.

What I'd like to have when I click my button:

1. Change `Enabled` of 1 or more buttons.
2. Run my function `ImportData` on another thread so my logger can keep logging. (`void ImportData(){}`)
3. Change `Enabled` of 1 or more buttons after my function is done doing something.

   ```
   private void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       //Disable current button
       btnImportData.Enabled = false;
       imgBonne.Visible = false; //random image
       rtConsole.Visible = true; //RichTextBox logger

       //Create a new thread for the button function    
       var t = new Thread(ImportData);
       t.Start();

       //It does NOT wait until thread stopped
       while (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Stopped)
       {
           //Never gets executed
           btnImportData.Enabled = true;
           btnExportBellijst.Enabled = true;
       }
   }
   ```

**Extra Info:** Screenshot from before pressing "Import Data": http://puu.sh/88oD6.png
Screenshot from after the application is done importing data: http://puu.sh/88oNT.png

*(edit)Target framework: .NET Framework 4*

I was originally using the code below, but this instantly enables all the buttons after pressing "Import Data".

```
    private void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgBonne.Visible = false; //random image
        rtConsole.Visible = true; //RichTextBox logger

        var t = new Thread(ImportData);
        t.Start();

        while (t.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
        {
            btnImportData.Enabled = false;
        }
        btnImportData.Enabled = true;
        btnExportBellijst.Enabled = true;
    }
```

**Edit:** I'm sorry if this is in the wrong category, I wanted to put it in c#.

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584062/how-to-wait-for-thread-to-finish-with-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can make it a whole lot easier:

```
private void btnImportData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgBonne.Visible = false; //random image
        rtConsole.Visible = true; //RichTextBox logger

        btnImportData.Enabled = false;

        Task.Run(ImportData).ContinueWith((Task task) =>
        {
            btnImportData.Enabled = true;
            btnExportBellijst.Enabled = true;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
```

Comment: thank you! However I apologize as I forgot to mention that I was using .NET Framework 4. I have changed Task.Run to Task.Factory.StartNew, but I can't seem to figure out how to get ContinueWith to work :s

Comment: What isn't working? The continuation isnt executing?

Comment: I'm getting an error when compiling: "Delegate 'System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' does not take 0 arguments" after replacing "Task.Run" with "Task.Factory.StartNew". (screenshot: http://puu.sh/88Lxd.png The green lines are from resharper, they're not an error, just a suggestion)  Edit: http://puu.sh/88LOh.png when hovering over the red lines it shows that.

Comment: Try ContinueWith((Task task) => {code here}). Edited my answer